# Apache httpclient connection takes too long

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm building a client that consumes a webservice.
One thing I need to do is to send a POST request then, store the returned cookie.
When I send it using a curl command, it takes about less than 2 seconds to get the response.
This is the command I used:

```
curl -c cookies.txt --cert client_certificate -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'request_body' "https://my_target_web_service"
```

But, when I use Apache httpclient (4.3.1), it takes about 5 seconds.
Following is the method:

```
@Test
public void firstCall() throws Exception {
    final String url = "https://my_target_web_service";
    final String requestBody = readFile("json/request_body.json");
    Executor executor = executor();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    executor.cookieStore(cookieStore);

    Request request = Request.Post(url).bodyString(requestBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    LOG.debug(request.toString());

    Response response = executor.execute(request);
    LOG.info(response.returnResponse().getStatusLine().toString());
}

private Executor executor() throws Exception {
    KeyStore clientStore = secretKeyStore();
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(clientStore, "secret_key".toCharArray()).useTLS().build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
    Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(httpclient);
    return executor;
}
```

LOG output shows that most of the time is spent in establishing the connection to the webservice (notice the jump from 15:44:12,610 to 15:44:17,426):

```
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:12,485] [main                          ] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: CookieSpec selected: best-match
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:12,500] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection request: [route: {s}->https://...:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:12,517] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://...:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:12,524] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec: Opening connection {s}->https://...:443
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:12,610] [main                          ] org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager: Connecting to ...:443
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:17,426] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec: Executing request POST / HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:17,427] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec: Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [2013-10-16 15:44:17,427] [main                          ] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec: Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing or doing wrong? Or, is this a limitation of httpclient and/or java?

Thanks,

Comment: did you compare the time after removing  LOG.debug and LOG.info lines from your coe..??

Comment: The Log statements won't affect that time, nor is this a "limitation" of HttpClient or Java. It's hard to say what's taking so long, but in any case performance tests like these should be made with several runs instead of a simple "1 vs. 1" call.

Comment: Use a profiler as jVisualVM or Java Mission Control to find out which method consumes the time. In my experience HttpClient is really fast but may take some time on initialization. Measure the time with the call to the `executor()` method. And do not call it on every request.